# Find past week, 2 days ago, yesterday and today with a PHP date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to use the chartist JS script in order to fill up a chart.
My need is to show entries all the way back til past week. But I'd like to separate them in "Past Week, 2 Days Ago, Yesterday and Today".

As I get all the entries from the database, there is a field that contains a datetime, I'd like to find a flexible way to compare against it for each above case and show the entries or not.

Tried something like,

```
$entrydate = explode(' ', $entry['datetime'])[0];

if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days', strtotime($entrydate)))) {
    echo 'past week';
} else if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days', strtotime($entrydate)))) {
    echo '2 days ago';
} else if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days', strtotime($entrydate)))) {
    echo 'yesterday';
} else {
    echo 'today'; //...
}
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not convert the dates to their textual representations. Instead I would use timestamps and an array to match timestamps to texts.

Something like:

```
$times = array(
   86400 => 'yesterday',
  172800 => 'two days ago'
  // etc
);

$time = strtotime($entrydate);

if ( $time < (time() - 172800) ) {
  echo $times[172800];
} elseif ( $time < (time() - 86400) ) {
  echo $times[86400];
}
// etc.
```

You could probably do this in a loop or more intelligently to avoid all the repetition, but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

Today:

```
date("Y-m-d");
```

Yesterday:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday"));
```

7 Days ago:
    date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days"));

Last Monday:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last Monday"));
```

[strtotime documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

To find Yesterday in relation to another day...

```
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2014-12-31") - 86400);

$sevendaysago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2014-12-31") - 7*86400);
```

Comment: So how do I use these in my case exactly? I tried if (date($entrydate, strtotime("yesterday"))) { echo 'is yesterday'; } for example and it always printed "is yesterday" although some dates were older or newer.

Comment: Got it solved but thanks for replying! Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **DateTime** object. I find **DateInterval** pretty useful sometimes.

```
$yourDate = "2014-12-28"; // The date to compare
$now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$from = new DateTime($yourDate);
$diff = $now->diff($from);
$diffByDays = $diff->days;

switch($diffByDays) {
    case 7:
        // One Week
        break;
    case 1:
        // Yesterday
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

**Result with print_r($diff):**

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 3
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

date() is going to return a string on success, FALSE on failure. The IF statements and ELSE IF statements are not going to evaluate as TRUE and print the desired results. Without running the code I'd expect that it only prints the final ELSE condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "today" ) );
date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "today -2 days" ) );
date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "today -7 days" ) );
date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "today -15 days" ) );
date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "today -1 month" ) );
```

;)